# Find common elements in two list

Tags: python, list

I have two list :

```
list_1 = ['rwww corp\pan 2323 2018-23-23 0% c:\program files\pa.txt', 'rwww corp\pand 2323 2018-23-23 0% c:\program files\monkey.txt']

list_2 = ['c:\program files\pa.txt']
```

I would like to find if list_2 element is there in list_1, if yes, then print that.

In this case, list_2 element is at index 0 for list_1, how can i use one liner to achieve this?

I have a boring way of doing this by using two for-loops:

```
for e in list_1:
    for k in list_2:
          if k in e:
               print e
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `list comprehension` here? It is basically used to create new lists. You can use it but you shouldn't. It will also have the same for loops with condition.

Comment: Not relavant to your question, but I notice you use \ characters in the string for a directory separator - this is dangerous if the character following happens to be a special character, like b, n, r.  Use a raw string, two backslashes, or a forward slash /.

Comment: Do you actually want to only print the elements here, or do you want to store them in a new list? You should only be using a list comprehension if it's the latter. Comprehensions for side effects only (such as printing) are discouraged  - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: What's wrong with `if list_2[0] in list_1:`?  If you have more, then convert to a `set` and use the `set` operations

Comment: the list shown here are for example, i have a big list, not possible to mention their index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of your loop using list comprehension:

```
[print e for e in list_1 for k in list_2 if k in e]
```

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to use a list comprehension for side effects, e.g. `print`

Comment: **@spejsy**, have you properly tested your code. As I've checked it. It doesn't give proper result. You are picking 2 items from 2 lists and using `in`(which is basically used with list, tuple, dict etc.).

Answer (score 1):

First I would look into `itertools.product()` and then I would not use a list comprehension for side effects, e.g.:

```
import itertools as it

print '\n'.join(e for e, k in it.product(list_1, list_2) if k in e)
```

I would also consider looking to the `__future__` and using the `print_function`, e.g.:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import itertools as it

print('\n'.join(e for e, k in it.product(list_1, list_2) if k in e))
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Petpan**, you can use `list comprehension` to fulfill your need.

> You should not use list comprehension for this.
>
> Try it online at http://rextester.com/QBQDO38144.

```
list_1 = ['rwww corp\pan 2323 2018-23-23 0% c:\program files\pa.txt', 
          'rwww corp\pand 2323 2018-23-23 0% c:\program files\monkey.txt', 
          'c:\program files\pa.txt',
          'c:\program files\pex2.txt',
          'c:\program files\pex5.txt',
          'c:\program files\pex4.txt',
          ]

list_2 = ['c:\program files\pa.txt', 'c:\program files\pex2.txt', 'c:\program files\pex3.txt',]

# You should not use list comprehension for this purpose
# It will print items in list_1 if it also exists in list_2
[print(e, 'exists in list_1') for e in list_2 if e in list_1]
```

» Output

```
c:\program files\pa.txt exists in list_1
c:\program files\pex2.txt exists in list_1
```